# App stuck in Awaiting Recurring Charge Cancellation, re-enable billing?

Tags: google-app-engine

My app, "tommienutest" is currently stuck in "Awaiting Recurring Charge Cancellation"-limbo. Is there any way to revert to the paying model?

Its been 2 days already and the change of payment was caused due to a misunderstanding. We'd really like to get our app up and running again (we hit the free limits in about 1 hour, leaving the app unusable for the other 23 hours).

Thanks for any assistance.
Tommie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you need someone from the AppEngine team to intervene. Why don't you try creating a Production issue through the link below.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue